# Question about 「その」 usage

Tags: grammar

I have a question about その手 part in this text. As far as I can guess 真琴 is talking about her own hand, but in this case shouldn't it be with この, "my hand". The only thought I have is that 真琴's hand, after becoming a doll like, already doesn't belong to "humans domain", but to the "dolls domain". In other words it belongs to someone she's talking with, who gave her this power or somethng.  In any case if my guess is incorrect, I would eally appreciate if you give me correct explanation.

> 暗い部屋の中、ひとりメールを打ち続ける。
>
> 光奈へのメールを打ち続ける。携帯の画面に、涙が滴る。
>
> 真琴：「……やだよ……もう、こんなの…」
>
> 膝を抱え、顔を埋める。クスクスと耳の奥で笑い声がする。
>
> 真琴：「誰……？」
>
> ???:「わたしは、あなた…だいじょうぶ、わたしを受け入れて…」
>
> すうっと頭の中の淀みが消えていく。
>
> 真琴：「なに、これ…？」
>
> **その手**は、人形の球体関節に変わっている。
>
> ???：「だいじょうぶ、これはあなたと彼女の絆…」
>
> 真琴：「光奈とあたしの…」
>
> ???:「あなたに、力をあげる。あの子を護れる力を…」
>
> 真琴：「光奈を護れる、力…」
>
> 人形となった自分の手を握り締める。
>
> 真琴：「へえ、だったら、うれしいな…」
>
> 光奈を護れる。あたしの力で、光奈を護れる。あのひとでもない。あの子たちでもない。あたしの力で、光奈を護れる。

```
光奈：「うう、さむ・・・・・・！」    
光奈？　光奈？　光奈？　こっちを見て。     
光奈：「あれ、真琴、リカとカナは？」    
やった。通じた・・・・・
```

・

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs to be 「その手」 because it is the narration, not [真琴]{まこと}'s line.

Comment: I think it's first-person narrative here, for example some lines before: 

 光奈：「うう、さむ・・・・・・！」

光奈？　光奈？　光奈？　こっちを見て。

光奈：「あれ、真琴、リカとカナは？」

やった。通じた・・・・・・

Comment: Yes, it is but you would still need to use two types of speech --- one for spoken lines and the other for narration.  For the first-person narration, you would keep a certain distance from yourself by using objective descriptions and observations, which is why you would describe your hand as if it were another's because of that distance.

Comment: So that's how it is, thank you very much for your explanation.